# ∀n∈ℕ:∑(-1)^(k+1)(1/k) [from k=1 to 2n] = ∑1/(n+k) [from k=1 to n]

Tags: summation, induction

> Prove by induction: $$
> \sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n+k}
> $$

I start with (using $n = t+1$):
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{2t+2}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{1}{k}=...
$$

but after expanding and attempting to simplify I get stuck at:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{t}\frac{1}{t+k} + (-1)^{2t}\frac{1}{2t+2}-(-1)^{2t}\frac{1}{2t+1}
$$

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: Show that the change in left hand side is same as the change in the right hand side as you go from $n$ to $n+1$.

Comment: Consider there are 3200 questions about proving something by induction on this site. The title should be way more specific than "prove by induction"